# ¿Cómo usar formula SI en excel con y sin referencia?

Tags: excel, formulas

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Estoy tratando de utilizar la formula SI en Excel 2013 para que me de dos resultados pero por más que intento no me da. Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es lo siguiente:

Si el número ingresado el al fila A2 es del 1 al 4 me marque como cliente contactado, pero si en B2 ingreso números del 5 al 7 sea cliente no contactado.

Esto lo repito en C3 y E4.

Adjunto un poco de lo que estoy haciendo.[image]

ACTUALIZACIÓN**

[image]

Comment: La información de contacto no se debe indicar en las preguntas/respuestas. Eso lo puedes en tu perfil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo haberte entendido

`=SI(Y(A3="";C3="";E3="");""; SI(O(Y(A3>0;A3<5);Y(C3>0;C3<5);Y(E3>0;E3<5));"CLIENTE CONTACTADO";"CLIENTE NO CONTACTADO"))`

es un anidado de formulas en la cual
el 1er SI, es para que no te de resultado hasta que se de algun valor a dichas celdas con la ayuda del resultado de la formula `Y(A3="";C3="";E3="")`
en caso de ser falso osea de tener valores se aplica el 2do SI, donde la función "O" te dará el resultado que buscas

Te dejo una captura del tester que le realize

[image]

Comment: Bienvenido. En este sitio las preguntas/respuestas no deben incluir saludos/despedidas. ref. https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior

Comment: Gracias, funciono a la perfección.

Answer (score 0):

no entendí muy bien pero creo que puedo darte una solución

`=SI(Y(A2>0;A2<5);"Contactado";SI(Y(A2>4;A2<8);"No contactado"))`

Esto pregunta si el número ingresado en la celda A2 es mayor a 0 y a su vez menor a 5 (1,2,3,4) si esto es verdadero en C2 escribe "Contactado"; en caso contrario vuelve a preguntar si el numero de A2 es mayor a 4 y menor que 8(5,6,7) si esto se cumple entonces escribe en C2 "No contactado".

Espero te sirva!

NOTA: A2, B1, C3 son CELDAS en una planilla de calculo, y una celda se forma por la intersección entre una fila (1, 2, 3,...) y una columna(A, B, C, ...)

Comment: Lo que pasa es que haga tres llamadas a x cliente. En la celda A2 escribo el número 1 indicando que fue un contacto efectivo y en la columna de estatus final debe de cambiar a "contactado", pero en caso de que el no contacte al cliente en la primera llamada no contacte y si en la segunda en la celda C2 ingreso el número 1 y debe cambiar en la columna estatus final "contactado".

En la pregunta agregare una segunda imagen de la formula que estaba ocupando pero me daño el archivo cuando puse esa formula, no se porque pero me funcionaba bien.

Comment: De igual manera un cuadro de rubros que ocupo y que significa cada número.